# heroku open: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello.py'; 'hello' is not a package

Tags: python, windows, flask

Help! I have been trying to figure this out for three days.  I am trying to implement the simplest possible "hello World" web app.  It works locally, but when I push it to Heroku and try "heroku open" I get the above error message within a three page output from "heroku logs --tail".

I would be happy to provide a zip of the entire project or anything else desired.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the most likely reason for the error is that **Heroku has closed its free plan** and you are trying to deploy your application for free. Heroku's free plan does not allow you to deploy Python applications, so you will need to use a different platform.

Here are some free alternatives to Heroku:

PythonAnywhere: PythonAnywhere is a cloud platform that allows you to deploy Python applications for free.
Firebase: Firebase is a platform that offers a variety of services, including a free plan for hosting Python applications.

I hope this helps!